# Declaring a variable of type `String` does not work

Tags: string, rust, variable-declaration

I just read [the Rust documentation about string data types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html), which states:

> Rust has more than only `&str`s though. A `String` is a heap-allocated
>   string. This string is growable, and is also guaranteed to be UTF-8.

**Trouble**: I want to explicitly declare variable type like follows:

```
let mystring : &str = "Hello"; // this works
let mystring : String = "Hello"; // this does not. Why?
```

Comment: Why downvotes? Answers to these questions helped me understanding Rust right away.

Comment: I don't know why this is getting downvoted. I think it's a good question.

Comment: Especialy, I came from high level language background. So Rust is pretty tought for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a `&str` is not a `String`.

There are a few ways you can make that string literal a `String` instance though:

```
let mystring = String::from("Hello");
// ..or..
let mystring: String = "Hello".into();
// ..or..
let mystring: String = "Hello".to_string();
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because the second `mystring` is not a `String`, but a `&'static str`, i.e. a statically allocated string literal.

In order to create a `String` in this manner (from a literal), you need to write `let mystring = String::from("Hello")` ([Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#examples)).